# I'm a mechanical engineering student, I don't know anything about coding. by learning Salesforce how much will it help with my career

Tags: developer, admin

I'm a mechanical engineering student, I don't know anything about coding. by learning Salesforce  how much will it help with my career. Please help should I learn it or not

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with SFSE

Comment: I would encourage you to explore your interest in Salesforce through discussion-based forums or your local user community, which you can locate at trailblazercommunitygroups.com. Salesforce Stack Exchange is for questions about building implementations on the Salesforce platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very opinion-based question, and thus not a good fit for the stackexchange network (which is focused on questions that can be definitively and authoratatively answered), but...

While many professions may benefit from at least *some* knowledge of programming, and while it's possible that you may end up using Salesforce at some point, I doubt that learning to customize Salesforce (writing code, lightning web components, process builder, etc...) will benefit a Mechanical Engineer.

Salesforce just isn't built to accomodate the type of tools you'll use to design and simulate mechanical systems.